# D3.js no value update in a tooltip

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I´m back with another d3.js problem.
I have an choropleth map and i want a tooltip which shows me the correct value of the community on an mouseover function.
It works nearly perfect, there is only one problem, there is no "update" of the value. on Every county it is the same.
I hope someone has an answer for me. Thank you.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var feature = group.selectAll("path")
    .data(collection.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    //.transition()
    //.duration(9000)
    .attr("fill",function(d) {

        //Get data value
        var value = d.properties.EINWOHNER;
        //console.log(value);

        if (value) {
                //If value exists…
                return color(value);
        } 
        else {
                //If value is undefined…
                return "none";
        }
    })

    .on("mouseover", function(d) {

        d3.select("#tooltip")
            .data(collection.features)
            .select("#value")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.properties.EINWOHNER;
            });

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
    })

    .on("mouseout", function() {

        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);                        
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the text, use

```
.text(d.properties.EINWOHNER);
```

You're currently getting the value from the data bound to the `#value` DOM element for each of them. You also don't need to pass in data there -- you already have the current data in `d`. So the complete code would look like this.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .text(d.properties.EINWOHNER);
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
})
```

Comment: Like the last time, you made it right. Thank you for that. A few more answers from you and I have to mention your name at my master thesis. And sorry for my english, it´s not to good. by the way your name sounds german